# Why does one approximation of pi equation decrease error, while the other increases it with more iterations?

Tags: approximation, matlab, pi

When approximating pi, these two equations give radically diffrent relative errors? is this due to floating point arithmetic or the equations themselves?

They remain relatively equal for the first 14 iterations however after that Equation 1 relative error increases while the other lowers. The initial value y1=2.0, and iterates to k=30. This culminates in equation 1 error getting worse till it equates itself to 0 rather than 3.141....

Is this due to precision or the equations themselves, and if the equations why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici both links show different to me. The first have the two equations the second shows the graph.

Answer (score 2):

If $y_k$ is reasonable sized, say about $\pi$, $\sqrt {(1-[2^{-k}y_k]^2)}$ suffers from cancellation as $k$ gets large.  The square brackets are about $10\cdot 2^{-2k}$, which in a $64$ bit float with $53$ bits of precision will be completely lost by the time $k=30$.  The square root will then be $1$ and when you subtract it from $1$ you get $0$, which is why the iteration converges on $0$.  The second one, which adds the square root to $1$ will stop changing when the square root becomes a solid $1$, but will leave $y_k$ the same.

Comment: So its loss of significance that is the issue, we are subtracting two numbers that are too close together, and end up with 0 which skews the calculation. Where as the reason that the second converges on pi is that it uses addition rather than subtraction which prevents the loss of precision. Am i understanding that correctly or did I totally butcher it. @RossMillikan

Comment: Yes, that is correct